# Iterator invalidation with unordered_set/unordered_multiset

Tags: c++, stl, hashtable, unordered-set, unordered-multiset

I know that `unordered_set` might invalidate iterators when elements are inserted:

> "If rehashing occurs (due to the insertion), all iterators are invalidated."

It is clear, because we have hash table with buckets, but why does `unordered_multiset` **not** invalidate iterators?
I think the implementation of `unordered_set` is almost identical with the implementation of `unordered_multiset` (hash table with buckets).

Comment: *why `unordered_multiset` does not invalidate iterators?* could you add a reference to this statement?

Comment: First function I check, rehashing in multiset also means iterator invalidation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset/insert

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no difference in this respect between `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_multiset`.

As you can see in the [`unordered_multiset::insert` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset/insert), it contains the exact same note as [`unordered_set::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert):

> If rehashing occurs (due to the insertion), all iterators are invalidated.

BTW - they are also identical in the case where there is no rehashing:

> Otherwise (no rehashing), iterators are not invalidated.

Note that it doesn't mean the two containers will always behave the same when it comes to invalidating iterators - because the implementation has some freedom (tweaking buckets count etc. which can affect rehashing - see @TonyDelroy's comment below).

Comment: "the policy controlling whether rehashing occurs can be different" - the policy/logic is set in stone by the C++ Standard - rehashing only occurs when `load_factor` exceeds `max_load_factor`, which is required to be set to 1.0 in the constructor, though client code can change it.  While the policy/logic of when rehashing occurs can't change, the implementation has freedom to tweak bucket counts and growth that feed into the rehashing policy calculation.

Comment: @TonyDelroy I rephrased. Feel free to rephrase again to make it more accurate. Anyway it is just a note. The main answer is that there is no difference in this respect, unlike what the OP suggested.

Comment: @marc_s thanks for fixing the spelling mistakes. I usually review what I write a little better.

Answer (score 0):

In the C++ Standard Library, the behavior of unordered_set and unordered_multiset regarding iterator invalidation during insertions might seem similar, but there are key differences in how duplicates are handled.

unordered_set:

In an unordered_set, each element is unique, and the insert operation might cause rehashing to occur if the load factor threshold is exceeded.
Rehashing involves changing the number of buckets in the hash table, which can invalidate iterators because the elements might be moved to new locations.
unordered_multiset:

`In an unordered_multiset, duplicate elements are allowed. When you insert an element, the insert operation adds it to the appropriate bucket without considering rehashing due to load factors. Since the number of buckets doesn't change during regular insertions (only when the container is resized), iterators are generally not invalidated during insertions.` The existing elements in a bucket are not affected by the insertion of a new element, and the iterator can still point to the correct bucket.
In summary, the key difference lies in the handling of duplicates. In an unordered_multiset, insertions of new elements don't trigger rehashing like in unordered_set, and therefore, iterators are less likely to be invalidated during regular insertions. It's always important to check the specific documentation or standard for the C++ implementation you are using, as details can vary between different standard library implementations.

and yes there is a difference, it might not be that much but its still a pretty valid one @wohlstad

Comment: I didn't claim the containers are identical. Of course there are differences. But they are not relevant to the OP's question about whether iterators in a `unordered_multiset` are invalidated due to rehashing. The OP quoted the specifications and asked _"why does unordered_multiset not invalidate iterators?"_ and the answer is (as I wrote) - they actually are invalidated if rehashing occurs - exactly like the `unordered_set`. The fact that the containers might rehash differently is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Also note that some of the details you mentioned are implementation specific and as far as I know not strictly required by the spec (even if it's a common implementation).

Comment: "the insert operation adds it to the appropriate bucket without considering rehashing due to load factors" - I believe this is flat-out wrong.  The C++ Standard [unord.req] says of all unordered containers "The number of buckets is automatically increased as elements are added to an unordered associative container, so that the average number of elements per bucket is kept below a bound. Rehashing invalidates iterators" - there's nothing about duplicate keys being considered one element (inherently non-sensical for `unordered_multimap`).  Any ref to support the claim?